# WordPress - update_post_meta not working for a field

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to save some simple meta data on a per post basis, but have discovered that the update_post_meta is not seeming to actually save meta data of one field.
The input field is that:

```
<input size="30" type="text" class="rwmb-text" id="themeum_movie_info_type" name="themeum_movie_info[0][themeum_movie_info_type]">
```

and i am trying this code to save meta data:

```
update_post_meta( $get_post_id, 'themeum_movie_info[0][themeum_movie_info_type]', 'Country:' );
```

Comment: could you please post your full code here

Comment: Full code here https://pastebin.com/XqPPBGtw

Comment: when you triggered `update_post_meta` function ? is there any specific event when you call this function ?

Comment: What did You try to do ? From your snippet( pastebin.com/XqPPBGtw ), WP try to put mete_key with name exactly (this string i mean, if its array it must be wrote $themeum_movie_info[themeum_movie_info_type] without quotes)`themeum_movie_info[themeum_movie_info_type]` (You can search in wp_postmeta table and see it) and put value `Country:` each time same for every post You created. Pls, read the manual how to use `update_post_meta` from codex( https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta ). At all, first param is ID, second - key, third - values to store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. We have to create an array and then have to put the array inside the update_post_meta function like this:

```
$array = array(
        '0' => array(
            'themeum_movie_info_type' => 'Country'
        )
);
update_post_meta( $get_post_id, 'themeum_movie_info', $array );
```